# Get a random item from Memcache - Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any way to get a random item from memcache?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  What statistical properties of randomness do you require?  There is no built in way of asking memcache for a random value.  However, there is probably a way to achieve your goal without this feature.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/3451052/281021. I was just wondering if it can benefit from any optimization using memcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to select a random element from memcache. It's not designed for that, either.

Comment: You helped provide this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/3451052/281021. Can memcache help there in any way?

Comment: @Albert No, because there's no way to query on memcache, only get by key.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly via API.

But you could create a list of image keys for all images in memcache and then randomly select from that list. The list itself would also need to me stored in memcache.

Comment: How would you know what images were in memcache, in order to create your list?  Items in memcache can disappear at any time with no warning.

Comment: As usual you try to get it from cache,  if not available load it from datastore.  The additional work is to add/remove entry from list when image is added/removed from memcache.

Comment: I assumed that going to the datastore is not acceptable.  To me the question is "can i get a random item that is in memcache right now, without going to the datastore"

Comment: If going to the datastore is acceptable, then you why do you need to keep track of what is in memcache?  Just select a random record from the datastore.

Comment: Also, what happens when the list itself disappears?