# Fetch a random entity from the datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, random, google-cloud-datastore

Pretty simple, in my AppEngine application, I have over 1 million entities of one kind, what is the best way to pick one at random?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get something random in datastore (AppEngine)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450926/how-to-get-something-random-in-datastore-appengine)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching a random record from the Google App Engine Datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002999/fetching-a-random-record-from-the-google-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching a random record from the Google App Engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002999/fetching-a-random-record-from-the-google-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get something random in datastore (AppEngine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450926/how-to-get-something-random-in-datastore-appengine)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See this question:

[Fetching a random record from the Google App Engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002999/fetching-a-random-record-from-the-google-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: @sag I don't know why 2010 me put this as an "answer" instead of voting to close as a duplicate - I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one solution but i don't know if it's the best :)

```
import random
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import memcache

DATA_KEY = "models/keys/random"

def get_data():
    data = memcache.get (DATA_KEY)
    if data is None:
        offset = random.randint (1, 1000000)
        data  = self.MyModel.all (keys_only=True).fetch (100, offset)
        memcache.add (DATA_KEY, data, 60)

    entity_key = random.choice (data)
    return db.get (entity_key)
```

Comment: The fetch will take increasing time as the size of the offset increases.  You should expect a DeadlineExceeded exception on nearly every request with this code.