# GQL Random Record

Tags: google-app-engine, random, gql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching a random record from the Google App Engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002999/fetching-a-random-record-from-the-google-app-engine-datastore)

How can I efficiently pick a random database record using GQL?

Eg. I have a Quotes Model and I need to pick a random quote every time. The question follows from my understanding that the ID attribute cannot be guaranteed to be auto-incremented with every insertion in the production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auto-generated ids are guaranteed to be unique, but not sequential or strictly increasing.

There are [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105004/querying-for-n-random-records-on-appengine-datastore) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002999/fetching-a-random-record-from-the-google-app-engine-datastore) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002999/fetching-a-random-record-from-the-google-app-engine-datastore) about this on [stackoverflow](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&q=google+app+engine+random+record#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=google+app+engine+random+record+stackoverflow&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=4824b41ba0d4cfd8), and in the groups.

There are several common solutions:

- Generate and store a random number
  on your entities as you create them,
  then pick a random number and look
  (via a query) for the closet
  record(s) to it.
- Implement some
  mechanism to ensure your entity ids
  are "densely" populated, then fetch
  within the known range using keys.
- Periodically generate random lists of
  the entities and return entities from
  those lists.  This may take the form
  of a stack that entities are popped
  off of, or as actual lists that are
  returned.

What you do *not* want to do is choose a random offset.  Offset is very inefficient because the datastore still has to scan over all of the skipped entities.